# Wi-Fi Verbose logging fields

Tags: wi-fi, logging

I've been trying to troubleshoot a Wi-Fi issue (with a specific network) and have Wi-Fi verbose logging on, but I can't find any documentation on what any of the fields in the network selection menu are.

The network in question has the full info of:

```
Connected [ UN UN UN ] f=2462 00:00:b1:6b:00:b5 standard=4 rssi=-75 score=59 tx=23.3,27.9,1.0 rx=20.9 4G STAs:8[(2)
```

I understand `rssi` and `STAs` (although, I have no idea for the second number for `STAs`) and `f` fits the channel frequency, but the rest (`UN`, `tx`/`rx`, `standard`, `score`, and `4G`) have me stumped.

Does anyone have any idea for these or a pointer to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Android source code is available online.

Your log line appears to be from:

[WifiStateMachine.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/a54399f/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java) specifically [String getLogRecString(Message msg)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/a54399f/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#2196)

Around line 2196, the string output starts looking similar to yours:

```
sb.append(" rssi=").append(mWifiInfo.getRssi());
sb.append(" f=").append(mWifiInfo.getFrequency());
sb.append(" sc=").append(mWifiInfo.score);
sb.append(" link=").append(mWifiInfo.getLinkSpeed());
sb.append(String.format(" tx=%.1f,", mWifiInfo.txSuccessRate));
sb.append(String.format(" %.1f,", mWifiInfo.txRetriesRate));
sb.append(String.format(" %.1f ", mWifiInfo.txBadRate));
sb.append(String.format(" rx=%.1f", mWifiInfo.rxSuccessRate));
```

The variables names appear reasonably descriptive for at least further research. The above file is dated 2017, given that there have been a number of WiFi changes made between OS version, I would find the one matching your version of OS, by looking for a "base" OS version branch (left hand side), and then drilling down to the appropriate `WiFiStateMachine.java` file:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/

or searching for an appropriate string where you can find where logging is occurring.